# Never resets list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a calorie counter the standard input goes like this:

```
python3 calories.txt < test.txt
```

Inside calories the food is the following format: apples 500

The problem I am having is that whenever I calculate the values for the person it seems to never return to an empty list..

```
    import sys

food = {}
eaten = {}
finished = {}

total = 0

#mappings 
def calories(x):  
    with open(x,"r") as file:
        for line in file:
            lines = line.strip().split()
            key = " ".join(lines[0:-1])
            value = lines[-1]
            food[key] = value

def calculate(x):
    a = []
    for keys,values in x.items():
        for c in values:
            try:
                a.append(int(food[c]))
            except:
                a.append(100)

    print("before",a)
    a = []
    total = sum(a) # Problem here
    print("after",a)
    print(total) 

def main():
    calories(sys.argv[1])
    for line in sys.stdin:
        lines = line.strip().split(',')
        for c in lines:
            values = lines[0]
            keys = lines[1:]
        eaten[values] = keys
        calculate(eaten)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit - forgot to include what test.txt would look like:

```
joe,almonds,almonds,blue cheese,cabbage,mayonnaise,cherry pie,cola
mary,apple pie,avocado,broccoli,butter,danish pastry,lettuce,apple
sandy,zuchini,yogurt,veal,tuna,taco,pumpkin pie,macadamia nuts,brazil nuts
trudy,waffles,waffles,waffles,chicken noodle soup,chocolate chip cookie
```

Comment: show some lines of  `test.txt` inputs.

Comment: [how to debug small programs - #3](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This is how standard input would look:            
joe,almonds,almonds,blue cheese,cabbage,mayonnaise,cherry pie,cola

Answer (score 0):

How to make it easier on yourself:

When reading the calories-data, convert the calories to `int()` asap, no need to do it every time you want to sum up somthing that way.
Dictionary has a [`.get(key, defaultvalue)` accessor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), so if food not found, use 100 as default is a 1-liner w/o `try: ...  except:`

This works for me, not using `sys.stdin` but supplying the second file as file as well instead of piping it into the program using `<`.

I modified some parsings to remove whitespaces and return a `[(name,cal),...]` tuplelist from calc.

May it help you to fix it to your liking:

```
def calories(x):  
    with open(x,"r") as file:
        for line in file:
            lines = line.strip().split()
            key = " ".join(lines[0:-1])
            value = lines[-1].strip() # ensure no whitespaces in
            food[key] = int(value)

def getCal(foodlist, defValueUnknown = 100):
    """Get sum / total calories of a list of ingredients, unknown cost 100."""
    return sum( food.get(x,defValueUnknown ) for x in foodlist) # calculate it, if unknown assume 100

def calculate(x):
    a = []
    for name,foods in x.items():
        a.append((name, getCal(foods))) # append as tuple to list for all names/foods eaten
    return a

def main():
    calories(sys.argv[1])
    with open(sys.argv[2]) as f: # parse as file, not piped in via sys.stdin
        for line in f:
            lines = line.strip().split(',')
            for c in lines:
                values = lines[0].strip()
                keys = [x.strip() for x in lines[1:]] # ensure no whitespaces in
                eaten[values] = keys
    calced = calculate(eaten) # calculate after all are read into the dict
    print (calced)
```

Output:

```
[('joe', 1400), ('mary', 1400), ('sandy', 1600), ('trudy', 1000)]
```

Using `sys.stdin` and piping just lead to my console blinking and waiting for manual input - maybe VS related...

Comment: Two quick things that stand out... You don't need `.readlines()` - you can just iterate directly over `f`... and it's probably worth making it `def getCal(foodlist, default=100)` and pass that in if required instead of putting the default inside the sum loop.

Comment: @JonClements readlines() removes `\n`? --->  nah it does not. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, good point, I would personally use `.split('\n')` though as it removes the confusion :)